# Merge [browser] and [webbrowser]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

According to their tag wikis, [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) and [webbrowser](/questions/tagged/webbrowser) refer to the same thing.

<s>While we're at it, [webbrowser](/questions/tagged/webbrowser) should probably be renamed to [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser).</s>

***EDIT***

[webbrowser](/questions/tagged/webbrowser) and [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser) has been made synonyms.

Although browser may refer to different kinds of browsers as Justin Satyr has mentioned, the term is usually used to refer to web browser, and the fact that the wiki tag suggests so doesn't help. It is necessary to disambiguate the [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) and merge the rest into [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser)

Comment: Quite a few of the questions in `webbrowser` are about the `WebBrowser` control in .NET. Perhaps these should be retagged to `webbrowser-control` or something similar?

Comment: Or just leave it the way it is, that's the name of the class.  No dash.  Nobody ever points their webbrowser to stackoverflow.com, that's a browser.

Comment: Update, 2.5 years in the future: [tag:webbrowser-control] now exists. [tag:browser] and [tag:web-browser] now have identical descriptions. Re-requesting tag merge. There may be other "browsers" that are not "web browsers" but not enough to warrant a tag at this time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A browser isn't necessarily a web browser. Other browsers include file browsers, directory browsers, search results browsers, network path browsers, help browsers, media browsers, etc. Most are derivatives of file browsers, but regardless there are several opportunities to use browser in a context other than web browsing.

Referring to a web browser as a browser is essentially slang. "Open your browser" honestly isn't that specific and it's through context that we know what "browser" refers to. If users have a question pertaining to *webbrowsers*, they should specify *webbrowser* in the tags.

Comment: In that case [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/browser/info) should be edited.

Answer (score 3):

Until [browser](/questions/tagged/browser)'s wiki:

> A web browser is a software application for retrieving, presenting, and traversing information resources on the World Wide Web...

and [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser)'s wiki:

> A web browser is a software application for retrieving, presenting, and traversing information resources on the World Wide Web.

**ARE SAME** one should be merged into another. I propose `web-browser`.

Answer (score 2):

I also believe that these should be merged ([browser](/questions/tagged/browser) and [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser)).

At this time, the description for [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) is:

> A software application for retrieving, presenting, and traversing information resources on the World Wide Web.

The description for [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser) is:

> A web browser is a software application for retrieving, presenting, and traversing information resources on the World Wide Web.

And the [webbrowser-control](/questions/tagged/webbrowser-control) tag that *hammar* referred to in the question comments has since been created.