# What is the difference between the browser and web browser tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

When tagging a question, when should [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) be used instead of [webbrowser](/questions/tagged/webbrowser)?

Both tag-wiki's read the same:

> a software application for retrieving, presenting, and traversing information resources on the World Wide Web.

Comment: The accepted answer on [this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108005/152859) is also the answer to this question.

Comment: As pointed out there, browser's tag-wiki needs editing then.

Comment: I think the term "browser" is very vague. It could mean many things. Although we all know what the most common use of it is, it could still mean things, such as `SQL Server Browser`. That being said, I would suggest merging `browser` into `webbrowser`. And actually I would rather it be `web-browser`.

Answer (score 2):

For developers, a **web** browser is for the World Wide Web. A **browser** might be used for looking up files on your hard drive.

As Justin said in his answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108005/152859)...

> A browser isn't necessarily a web browser. Other browsers include file browsers, directory browsers, search results browsers, network path browsers, help browsers, media browsers, etc. Most are derivatives of file browsers, but regardless there are several opportunities to use browser in a context other than web browsing.
>
> Referring to a web browser as a browser is essentially slang. "Open your browser" honestly isn't that specific and it's through context that we know what "browser" refers to. If users have a question pertaining to webbrowsers, they should specify webbrowser in the tags.

Comment: I think whatever reasoning we do on meta, most people on the main site are not likely to be aware of and will just misuse the tags. Currently, browser is being used mostly to refer to web browser.

Comment: Even if users were aware, is there any value in a tag which covers all types of browsers? I can't imagine anyone having a particular interest or expertise in browsers as you've defined them.